# User can't log in using local copy of Chrome

Tags: login, chrome

This isn't the usual "I can't log in" issue. A user is trying to log in on her copy of Chrome and cannot. She gets "Invalid username or password" errors every time. She then used Safari and it worked for a day, now it too won't let her log in. The same user account on a different computer works just fine. It applies to logging into the control panel and front end login forms. She says no other websites give login issues.

If that wasn't strange enough, other user accounts WORK!? It is just isolated to her username (her email address).

We cleared all the browsing data in Chrome and looked over the cookies to make sure there were not any for this site. Short of uninstalling Chrome and reinstalling it I'm not sure what else to do.

There are the usual fixes we tried: setting security to session ID or Cookies only, playing with the server's date settings, etc. Nothing worked.

To sum up:
logging in with her username/password works on every computer but hers.
Logging in on her computer with other usernames and passwords work.

Comment: any extensions in Chrome? Did you cleanup form history too?

Comment: Chrome is pretty stock and we cleared everything out. She is sure to manually type in the username and password.

Comment: Now she reports Safari is doing the same thing...

Comment: try to replace keybord... and possible user hands. It is most possible the reason of this issues. Just for sure - is she entered domain with subdomain or not? You can also check what exactly(name/pass) login form send to the server by open Network panel in Chrome developer form.

Comment: We can reproduce the error quite easily, definitely not user error (which is my go to answer and is the reason 99% of the time). The account only works on machines other than hers. We even tried creating a new account and that only works on every other machine than hers. 

Definitely something about her system that doesn't like this site. It looks like it isn't EE related, but I'll do more testing.

Comment: Is she using Mavericks? Has the wrong password been saved into her Keychain? Is she using iCloud to sync passwords? The fact that it happens on both Chrome and Safari makes me think it might be Keychain related.

Comment: Try pinging the serve from her machine to make sure she's connecting to the correct server. It's not impossible that DNS could be cached for her and she's connecting to old server without the Username?

Comment: We did use the Chrome developer tools to inspect the form data. It is sending the right username and password to the right server.

Comment: Next, I'd turn on query debugging and see if you can grab the query that's running and check it by manually. Or turn on mysql logging on the server to grab it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never were able to figure out what wasn't right. We eventually had to remove Chrome and re-install it. Since then it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a DNS issue - try clearing DNS cache http://www.ihash.eu/2013/10/clear-dns-cache-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks/